# How to reference another constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

How to reference another constructor in c#? For example

```
class A
{
    A(int x, int y) {}

    A(int[] point)
    {
      how to call A(point.x, point.y}?
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use `keyword` `this` in the Constructor

Answer (score 2):

You can use keyword `this` in the "derived" constructor to call the "this" constructor:

```
class A
{
    A(int x, int y) {}

    A(int[] point) : this(point[0], point[1]) { //using this to refer to its own class constructor
    {

    }    
}
```

That aside, I think you should get the value in array by indexes: `point[0], point[1]` instead of doing it like getting field/property: `point.x, point.y`

Comment: No, that's a `this` constructor, not a `base` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. Same way you would call a base constructor.

```
A(int[] point) : this(point[0], point[1])
{
}
```

Comment: That's not a `base` constructor.

Comment: I never said that?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread.